# Print to file in Python?

Tags: python, printing

I've looked at tutorials on how to print to a file in Python, but I'm still have a problem. When I do:

```
x = a_function_that_spits_out_a_table
print x
```

The table looks great and is formatted properly. But when I do:

```
f=open(myfile,"w")
print >> f, x
```

I get a file with one line of text, without any line breaks. How do I print to a file exactly as how it appears when I use the print command?

Comment: And what does `print repr(x)` look like? All `print >> fobj` does is write to a different file object instead of `sys.stdout` so the output is **exactly the same** for both methods.

Comment: Are you using correct line breaks? For example stdout will make a new line for \n (and most of text editors) but notepad.exe( windows) won't, it does just for "\r\n".

Comment: print repr(x) looks like one single line, with line breaks as \n included. When I write to the text file, I don't see the line breaks, I just see a space where line breaks should be, a la: "top of table bottomoftable".

Comment: See @at0ma comment. I most definitely bet on an end-of-line issue between terminal and windows notepad, or something nasty like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would work:

```
print  >> f, "{line_content} \n".format(line_content=x)
```

format string method is easy to use.

See doc: [format method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings)

**Note:** Even though I've written new line character as "\n", Python may convert '\n' characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading. See here: [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: Nevermind, does work when opened in Notepad++. Thanks!

Comment: @user1566200 This is a line-ending issue. Windows' notepad breaks lines only with `\r\n`, and you're feeding it a file with `\n`  only. Subtle!

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves Python may convert '\n' characters to a platform-specific representation on writing and back on reading. See here: python doc